# How did Missy survive?

Tags: doctor-who

At the season finale of season 10,

> the Saxon master kills Missy.

How, then, did she regenerate into the latest Master?

Comment: With the precedent of the Curator - there is the possibility that that is not the Saxon Master but a favorite old face. Additionally the timelords can resurrect someone using the mind copy stored in the Matrix.  This was presumably how he came back from his death in the Paul McGann movie  - drafted to fight in the timewar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no in-universe or in-canon way (as of the last episodes in which we saw him, anyway) to genuinely know even whether the most recently seen Master is "newer" than Missy, or is a previous regeneration the Doctor hadn't encountered before Missy.

Beyond that, the Doctor is always changing timelines, even *Fixed Points in Time*: undoing the Time War destruction of Gallifrey, for instance, or her own permanent death at the hands/gun of River Song or at Trenzalore.  Who's to say the Saxon Master didn't change his own timeline, with foreknowledge, in a way that erased his regeneration into Missy after their last meeting?  Don't forget, it's all wibbly-wobbly, timey-wimey...*stuff*.

Comment: Long answer short: It's _Doctor Who_ - they write whatever they feel like and hand-wave away any inconsistencies. _;)_